# How to prevent IE11 response to network errors

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

My javascript application has its own error handling (and UI support) for dealing with comms errors with the server.  For testing, I'm inducing comms errors by simply severing the network connection (turning off the wifi).

All good in Chrome/Safari... IE 11, however, will *replace* my content with its own network loss messages, like "This page can't be displayed" (i.e., shows dnserrordiagoff.htm).  This is, in short, annoying and undesired.  Is there any way to suppress it?

Bonus:  Firefox 43 is kind enough to replace my content with a blank/empty window.  Any thoughts?

Thanks all, -Pete

Comment: I did a quick google search, but almost all hits where on end user support sites, where people asked how they could change this page _locally_ on their own machine; didn’t come across anything that suggested you could do something about it from the server side (which makes sense, because the connection to your server is no more.) Perhaps you could intervene on the client side, if you stopped using normal links and forms altogether, and made _everything_ AJAX based – suppose that could work, in that you’d get an error code/exception that you could then handle accordingly.

Comment: Whether that’s worth the hassle, I wouldn’t know … I suppose that a) total network/connectivity loss would be a rather rare occurrence, or b) that if it was more common, IE users might already be used to seeing this message, and would know it is not your app’s “fault.”

Comment: Perhaps it could be even viewed the other way around – the “blank” page Firefox serves up gives the user no clue as to what’s going on, and just leaves them with a “what the … is wrong with stupid app?” feeling. IE at least alerts the user as to what the issue is, and probably also makes suggestions as to how it might be fixed (however successful those might turn out to be.) And in the very least, it could help the poor hey-you-know-computers-dont-you victims that will be dragged in to help, to get a searchable error message, and not just _“it just went blank, and I was like d’oh …?”_ :-)

Comment: All server communications are synchronous via AJAX, which allows me to response to error codes, exceptions, etc., within the app.  That IE11/Firefox essentially prevent me from doing that is a problem.  I don't want to do anything from the server side - just want to be able to display my own UI (with helpful things like links to support sites, ability to access more detailed internal error codes, etc.).